# How do I store (adjoint) functors in a pair?

Tags: c++, functor

I have two functors which are adjoint i.e. they occur in pairs
If one is `doX()` , the other will be `undoX()`.

They have been declared like so:

```
    template< typename T >
    struct doSomething{
        void operator()( T &x ) const {

        .....
        .....
        .....

        }
    };


    template< typename T >
    struct undoSomething{
        void operator()( T &x ) const {

        .....
        .....
        .....

        }
    };
```

These are used by a class on it's member variables.

How can I store them in an std::pair which I can pass in the class's constructor?

P.S. A solution without C++11 or boost would be appreciated. But I'm willing to use them as a last resort

Answer (score 2):

Container class:

```
struct Container
{
   typedef int DoUndoType; // This is an example, the actual type will
                           // have to be decided by you.

   // The constructor and its argument.
   Container(std::pair<doSomething<DoUndoType>,
                       undoSomething<DoUndoType>> const& doUndoPair) : doUndoPair(doUndoPair) {}

   std::pair<doSomething<DoUndoType>,
             undoSomething<DoUndoType> doUndoPair;
};
```

Use of Container class:

```
// Construct an object.
Container c(std::make_pair(doSomething<Container::DoUndoType>(),
                           unDoSOmething<Container::DoUndoType>()));

// Use the pair.
int arg = 10;
c.doUndoPair.first(arg);
c.doUndoPair.second(arg);
```

Comment: How do I use the functors in this? Do I use c.first and c.second ?

Comment: @ShayanRC I expanded my answer to address your question.

Comment: @ShayanRC You have defined the `operator()` function to take a `T&`. Now that I think about it, unless that is changed to `T const&`, the code I wrote won't compile.

Comment: @ShayanRC 10 is just an sample value. You have to choose a value that is more appropriate for the operation you are performing.

Comment: I tried coding this.. But it's giving an error : doSomething and undoSomething could not be resolved.

Comment: @ShayanRC it's hard to suggest something useful without looking at all the code and the full error message.